# Capture SQL before ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteReader statement without modifying current logic

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlcommand

In my current project, they have built huge application which is not using any ORM but does all CRUD operations using dynamic SQL and then using `ExecuteNonQuery`, `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteScalar`.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();   // want to capture queryString before execution
}
```

There is no logging to capture SQL text so I am thinking if I can handle and "PreExecute" event for above 3 methods, I can put this logging right there and does have to modify their tons of DAO files.

I did not find anything related to such PreExecute event so how can we do that? I read about wrapper class but did not exactly get how it would help me?

Comment: You could have SQL Server Profiler on the SQL Server end log all the SQL that comes its way into a file or database table ....

Comment: I am familiar with it and does not help for what I want to achieve.

Comment: I don't think the regular SqlCommand  will do this for you. so so would have to make your project use a subclass that has the logging capabilty added. Simple to write but probably hard to get approved by project manager..